# ion-buttons start and end syntax makes no sense

Tags: button, ionic-framework, syntax, ionic2

I have two problems with **`ion-buttons`**.

1. The ionic documentation only shows usage of the **`ion-buttons`** element with no real explanation beyond what you can infer from the example.
2. What throws me off about this is the close tags appear to me to be in the wrong place.

When I saw this on the docs I wondered if it was a mistake, but I've also seen this in a code example here on stack. Like this one:

```
<ion-header>
  <ion-navbar primary>
    <ion-buttons start>       **// here it starts.**
      <button menuToggle>
        <ion-icon name="menu"></ion-icon>
      </button>
    </ion-buttons>  **//Why does ion-buttons close here?** 

    <ion-title>
      My Page
    </ion-title>

    <ion-buttons end> **// END here?** 
      <button  ion-button icon-only>
        <ion-icon name="search"></ion-icon>
      </button>
    </ion-buttons> **// then close AGAIN here when there is no companion open tag?**
  </ion-navbar>
</ion-header>
```

Comment: what is your question?

Comment: if you look at the code snippet you'll see where i note my questions

Comment: the `start` and `end` is not like you think it is. Think of it as left and right markers. Each `<ion-buttons>` closes with `</ion-buttons>`, as usual

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
 <ion-buttons start>       **// here it starts.**
```

Actually here `start` mean not the start of **ion-buttons**. Here `start` mean according to their [documentation](http://ionicframework.com/docs/theming/css-utilities/) . Just help to do button alignment.

> Aligns the element at the start based on platform. iOS goes left,
>   Android is the first item on the right

*Refer the **ion-buttons property** section.*

```
</ion-buttons>  **//Why does ion-buttons close here?**
```

Here actually close the previously opened **ion-buttons**  that is  `<ion-buttons start>`
as we do normally like this `<ion-buttons> </ion-buttons>`

```
 <ion-buttons end> **// END here?**
```

Here `end` mean not the end of **ion-buttons**. According to their [documentation](http://ionicframework.com/docs/theming/css-utilities/). Just help to do button alignment.

> Aligns the element at the end based on the platform. iOS goes right,
>   Android is the last item on the right

*Refer the **ion-buttons property** section.*

```
</ion-buttons> **// then close AGAIN here when there is no companion open tag?**
```

Again we are going to close the previously open  `<ion-buttons end>` tag. As we do normally like this `<ion-buttons> </ion-buttons>`. The **companion open tag** for this is `<ion-buttons end>` tag.  Don't get confuse with the `end` inside the tag. That `end` really help to do the button alignment that is it. Don't think beyond that :).

Hope this will help to you. Cheers!

Answer (score 11):

There is no issue.Those are CSS Utilities where `start` and `end` follow the UI pattern for the platform.Please see below for more detail about it.

[image]

You can see full list here: [**CSS-Utilities (ion-buttons property)**](http://ionicframework.com/docs/theming/css-utilities/)

**Brief explanation** by **@sebaferreras**

Just like you can see in [this post](https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/nav-bar-with-button-on-left-side/51963/5), *mhartington* (from Ionic Team) explains:

> Start and End follow the UI pattern for the platform
>
> So `<ion-buttons start>` would be on the left for ios and be the first
>   button on the right for android.
>
> `<ion-buttons end>` would be on the right for ios and the last button on
>   the right for android.
>
> Left/right are provide as a way to over ride that.

So if you want to place the button on the left for both android and ios, use the `left` css utility.

By **[Ionic Team Member Mike Hartington](https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/nav-bar-with-button-on-left-side/51963/4)**

> Nope,
>
> Start and End follow the UI pattern for the platform
>
> So  would be on the left for ios and be the first
>   button on the right for android.
>
> would be on the right for ios and the last button on
>   the right for android.
>
> Left/right are provide as a way to over ride that.

Comment: I've added a brief explanation to your answer, hope you don't mind :)

Comment: It's perfectly OK.Thanks :) @sebaferreras

Comment: I have shared an official doc above.Can you tell us what are the issues you have now? http://ionicframework.com/docs/theming/css-utilities/ see under the (ion-buttons property).

Answer (score 8):

If anyone is trying to place a button on either end of the title, both left and right, the following syntax is current as of Ionic 3.19.0. Using `left` and `right` rather than start and end.

```
<ion-navbar>
    <ion-title>Title</ion-title>
    <ion-buttons left>
        <button left ion-button icon-only (click)="addItem()">
            <ion-icon name="add"></ion-icon>
        </button>
    </ion-buttons>
    <ion-buttons right>
        <button right ion-button icon-only (click)="presentPopover($event)">
            <ion-icon
              [name]="poppedOver ? 'close' : 'menu'"
            ></ion-icon>
        </button>
    </ion-buttons>
</ion-navbar>
```

Comment: Worked for me :)